# Rails | $mq-mobile Undefined Variable in Sass

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, bower

I am working with a Rails Theme I downloaded from wrapbootstrap.com and it runs locally without changing anything. I've copied over all the CSS/JS views/controller files into a Rails 5 application and installed Bower locally however I keep getting an error:

`Sass::SyntaxError at /
Undefined variable: "$mq-mobile".`

I've seemed to have tried what I could think of and from some suggestions online:

1. Have bower install all the dependencies (to the best of my knowledge)
2. Try to go through all the code in the older Rails 4.1.x project and compare files in the Rails 5 project.
3. Make sure all the files are in the same directory structure
4. Check all file extensions
5. Check that the variable **$mq-mobile** is indeed undefined in the files but how is it working in the original project?

Now I'm not sure which way to turn to aside from SO.

The Error output is as follows:

```
Sass::Script::Tree::Variable#_perform
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/script/tree/variable.rb, line 49
Sass::Script::Tree::Variable#perform
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb, line 58
block in Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform#run_interp_no_strip
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb, line 542
Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform#run_interp_no_strip
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb, line 540
Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform#run_interp
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb, line 547
Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform#visit_media
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb, line 512
Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform#visit
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb, line 36
block in Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform#visit
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb, line 160
block in Sass::Stack#with_base
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/stack.rb, line 79
Sass::Stack#with_frame
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/stack.rb, line 115
Sass::Stack#with_base
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/stack.rb, line 79
Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform#visit
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb, line 160
block in Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform#visit_children
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb, line 52
Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform#visit_children
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb, line 52
block in Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform#visit_children
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb, line 169
Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform#with_environment
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb, line 181
Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform#visit_children
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb, line 168
block in Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform#visit
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb, line 36
Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform#visit_root
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb, line 188
Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform#visit
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb, line 36
Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform#visit
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb, line 159
Sass::Tree::Visitors::Perform.visit
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb, line 8
Sass::Tree::RootNode#css_tree
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb, line 36
Sass::Tree::RootNode#render
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb, line 20
Sass::Engine#render
sass (3.4.22) lib/sass/engine.rb, line 281
Sass::Rails::ScssTemplate#evaluate
sass-rails (5.0.6) lib/sass/rails/template.rb, line 47
Sass::Rails::ScssTemplate#render
tilt (2.0.5) lib/tilt/template.rb, line 102
Sprockets::LegacyTiltProcessor#call
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/legacy_tilt_processor.rb, line 25
Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#call_processor
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb, line 75
block in Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#call_processors
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb, line 57
Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#call_processors
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb, line 56
Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#load_from_unloaded
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb, line 134
block in Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#load
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb, line 60
Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb, line 317
Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#load
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb, line 44
block in Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#initialize
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb, line 20
Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#load
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb, line 47
block in Sprockets::Bundle.call
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb, line 23
Sprockets::Utils.dfs
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/utils.rb, line 196
Sprockets::Bundle.call
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb, line 24
Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#call_processor
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb, line 75
block in Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#call_processors
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb, line 57
Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#call_processors
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb, line 56
Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#load_from_unloaded
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb, line 134
block in Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#load
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb, line 60
Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb, line 317
Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#load
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/loader.rb, line 44
block in Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#initialize
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb, line 20
Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#load
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb, line 47
Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#find_asset
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb, line 66
Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#find_all_linked_assets
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb, line 73
block in Sprockets::Manifest#find
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb, line 142
block (2 levels) in Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#logical_paths
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb, line 114
block in Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#stat_tree
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb, line 228
block in Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#stat_directory
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb, line 212
Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#stat_directory
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb, line 209
Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#stat_tree
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb, line 227
block in Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#logical_paths
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb, line 105
Sprockets::CachedEnvironment#logical_paths
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/legacy.rb, line 104
Sprockets::Manifest#find
sprockets (3.7.0) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb, line 140
Moscars::Application#precompiled_assets
sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb, line 50
Moscars::Application#asset_precompiled?
sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb, line 35
block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>
sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/railtie.rb, line 250
Sprockets::Rails::HelperAssetResolvers::Environment#precompiled?
sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb, line 342
Sprockets::Rails::HelperAssetResolvers::Environment#raise_unless_precompiled_asset
sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb, line 346
Sprockets::Rails::HelperAssetResolvers::Environment#find_debug_asset
sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb, line 331
block in #<Class:0x007fc2f8bc8e38>#lookup_debug_asset
sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb, line 212
block in #<Class:0x007fc2f8bc8e38>#resolve_asset
sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb, line 225
#<Class:0x007fc2f8bc8e38>#resolve_asset
sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb, line 224
#<Class:0x007fc2f8bc8e38>#lookup_debug_asset
sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb, line 211
block in #<Class:0x007fc2f8bc8e38>#stylesheet_link_tag
sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb, line 153
#<Class:0x007fc2f8bc8e38>#stylesheet_link_tag
sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb, line 152
#<Class:0x007fc2f8bc8e38>#_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1177409203046223770_70237686521380
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb, line 12
block in ActionView::Template#render
actionview (5.0.0) lib/action_view/template.rb, line 158
ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb, line 166
ActionView::Template#instrument
actionview (5.0.0) lib/action_view/template.rb, line 348
ActionView::Template#render
actionview (5.0.0) lib/action_view/template.rb, line 156
ActionView::TemplateRenderer#render_with_layout
actionview (5.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb, line 66
ActionView::TemplateRenderer#render_template
actionview (5.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb, line 52
ActionView::TemplateRenderer#render
actionview (5.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb, line 14
ActionView::Renderer#render_template
actionview (5.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb, line 42
ActionView::Renderer#render
actionview (5.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb, line 23
PageController#_render_template
actionview (5.0.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb, line 103
PageController#_render_template
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb, line 217
PageController#render_to_body
actionview (5.0.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb, line 83
PageController#render_to_body
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb, line 52
PageController#render_to_body
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb, line 144
PageController#render
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb, line 26
PageController#render
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb, line 36
block (2 levels) in PageController#render
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb, line 44
block in Benchmark.ms
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb, line 12
Benchmark.realtime
/Users/aneilyounis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb, line 308
Benchmark.ms
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb, line 12
block in PageController#render
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb, line 44
PageController#cleanup_view_runtime
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb, line 87
PageController#cleanup_view_runtime
activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb, line 25
PageController#render
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb, line 43
PageController#default_render
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb, line 36
block in PageController#send_action
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb, line 4
PageController#send_action
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb, line 4
PageController#process_action
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb, line 188
PageController#process_action
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb, line 30
block in PageController#process_action
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb, line 20
ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Filters::End#call
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb, line 126
block (2 levels) in ActiveSupport::Callbacks::CallbackChain#compile
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb, line 506
ActiveSupport::Callbacks::CallbackSequence#call
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb, line 455
PageController#__run_callbacks__
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb, line 101
PageController#_run_process_action_callbacks
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb, line 750
PageController#run_callbacks
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb, line 90
PageController#process_action
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb, line 19
PageController#process_action
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb, line 20
block in PageController#process_action
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb, line 32
block in ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb, line 164
ActiveSupport::Notifications::Instrumenter#instrument
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb, line 21
ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb, line 164
PageController#process_action
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb, line 30
PageController#process_action
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb, line 248
PageController#process_action
activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb, line 18
PageController#process
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb, line 126
PageController#process
actionview (5.0.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb, line 30
PageController#dispatch
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb, line 190
PageController.dispatch
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb, line 262
ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher#dispatch
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb, line 50
ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher#serve
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb, line 32
block in ActionDispatch::Journey::Router#serve
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb, line 39
ActionDispatch::Journey::Router#serve
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb, line 26
ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet#call
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb, line 725
block in Warden::Manager#call
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb, line 35
Warden::Manager#call
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb, line 34
Rack::ETag#call
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/etag.rb, line 25
Rack::ConditionalGet#call
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb, line 25
Rack::Head#call
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/head.rb, line 12
ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore#context
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb, line 222
ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore#call
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb, line 216
ActionDispatch::Cookies#call
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb, line 613
ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending#call
activerecord (5.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb, line 552
block in ActionDispatch::Callbacks#call
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb, line 38
ActionDispatch::Callbacks#__run_callbacks__
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb, line 97
ActionDispatch::Callbacks#_run_call_callbacks
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb, line 750
ActionDispatch::Callbacks#run_callbacks
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb, line 90
ActionDispatch::Callbacks#call
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb, line 36
ActionDispatch::Reloader#call
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb, line 12
ActionDispatch::RemoteIp#call
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb, line 79
BetterErrors::Middleware#protected_app_call
better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb, line 84
BetterErrors::Middleware#better_errors_call
better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb, line 79
BetterErrors::Middleware#call
better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb, line 57
ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions#call
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb, line 49
WebConsole::Middleware#call_app
web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb, line 131
block in WebConsole::Middleware#call
web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb, line 28
WebConsole::Middleware#call
web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb, line 18
ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions#call
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb, line 31
Rails::Rack::Logger#call_app
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb, line 36
block in Rails::Rack::Logger#call
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb, line 24
block in ActiveSupport::Logger#tagged
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb, line 70
ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter#tagged
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb, line 26
ActiveSupport::Logger#tagged
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb, line 70
Rails::Rack::Logger#call
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb, line 24
Sprockets::Rails::QuietAssets#call
sprockets-rails (3.1.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb, line 13
RequestStore::Middleware#call
request_store (1.3.1) lib/request_store/middleware.rb, line 9
ActionDispatch::RequestId#call
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb, line 24
Rack::MethodOverride#call
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb, line 22
Rack::Runtime#call
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb, line 22
ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware#call
activesupport (5.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb, line 28
ActionDispatch::Executor#call
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb, line 12
ActionDispatch::Static#call
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb, line 136
Rack::Sendfile#call
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb, line 111
Moscars::Application#call
railties (5.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb, line 522
Puma::Configuration::ConfigMiddleware#call
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb, line 225
Puma::Server#handle_request
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb, line 578
Puma::Server#process_client
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb, line 415
block in Puma::Server#run
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb, line 275
block in Puma::ThreadPool#spawn_thread
puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb, line 116
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @Rob I was not able to. I ended up making the Rails 4.1.x project a Rails 5 by following people's suggestions on how to upgrade to the latest version. Turned out that there's a newer Rails 5 version of the same project which was a free download so going to start working with that eventually. Upgrading is a pain and some of the ActionCable things didn't seem to work in the new project like they were supposed to so I gave up on that idea.